# JSON Array Value Color Change

Tags: android, arrays, json

If my json file is

```
[{name:xxxb fname:dddd tag1:F no:43434},{name:yyy fname:dfff tag1:T no:46464},{name:bbbb fname:nnnn tag1:F no:76676},{name:trtr fname:ghgh tag1:T no:5666}]
```

and so on
I am getting the all the  display in the listview in eclipse android emulator but how do I change the color of my json value 'add'.
In other words if the json value add:F then F should be shown in red in my listview else if the add:T then T should be shown in red.

Answer (score -1):

Please check out [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) API:

```
JSONObject jsonObject;
String color, item;
String str = "<font color=\"%s\">%s</font>";
// handle the exception here
item = jsonObject.getString("add")
if("F".equalsIgnoreCase(item)){
   color = "red";
}else if("T".equalsIgnoreCase(item)){
   color = "green";
}else{
    color = "blue";
}
// and inside your ArrayAdapter
itemTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format(Locale.US, str, color, item)));
```

Comment: Lol. Someone just earned their review privileges.

Comment: Thnx.. bt what I want is a kind of an if else loop in my mainactivity java file which will show the color red if the json value add:F else if json value add:T then any other color..

Comment: `if(jsonObj.getString("add") == "F"){ ... }`

Comment: Thnx chx101..u gt my point ..bt can u b a bit more elaborate as to where do I put this condition and what comes in {....}..m a newbie to this....could u provide me an example plzz

Comment: thnx chx101 but i am getting this error on using switch "Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted"

Comment: hi thnx chx101..but it dint help..i am posting my java code..wld b obliged if you cld help me in this

Comment: but my code is long..unable to post in comments..where can i post it plzz

Comment: I have posted a new question...kindly have a look

Comment: Give me the link if you want me to look at it. It's a forest out there